# Circuit Complexity Query regarding the minimum circuit size and input size range

Tags: complexity-theory

Given a boolean function it can always be represented by a family of circuits.

**Query 1:** Is it true that, for any integer $N$ and for all $I_{in}$ such that $I_{in} \leq 2N$

There exists a circuit of size $N$ with $I_{in}$ input bits such that this same logic cannot be created with a smaller circuit.

**Query 2:** We know that a classical gate can have at most 2 input bits, thus the input size will be upper bounded by $I_{in} \leq 2N$. But for the above statement to be true what is the lower bound for the input bits?

Note: For the sake of simplicity we can assume $I_{in}=I_{out}$ (if that helps).

Can someone please help with the proof of this?